# Matlab indexing variable for a specific element or the last element

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I want to define an indexing variable at the beginning of a function to subsequently index several vectors. The index should point to a specific element (eg element nr 3) or to the last entry of the vectors.

I hoped to be able to make the indexing variable a string and evaluate it.

In case of a specific element it would be:

```
idx = '3';
vector1(eval(idx))
vector2(eval(idx))
```

This works. But for the last element the approach fails:

```
idx = 'end';
vector1(eval(idx))
vector2(eval(idx))
```

just as eval('end'), it throws the following error:

> Error: Illegal use of reserved keyword "end".

Does anyone know a solution how to set up an indexing variable, so that it can index to a specific element or the last element of vectors with unknown size?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose in making the index variable "a string"?  I don't understand what's wrong with just using `vector(end)`.  That's what the `end` keyword is for.  Your use of `eval` implies that `end` is a variable when it isn't allowed. No need to store it as a variable and you can't anyway.  It's a **reserved** keyword.  Downvoting my (deleted) answer won't help in solving your problem.  A lot of the other MATLAB users will ask you the same questions I did.

Comment: Why make the index variable a string?

Comment: First, get rid of the string indexing.  Second, build your index vectors explicitly using `length(vector1)` or `length(vector2)`.  If this means you won't be able to use the same index vector, start considering other solutions, like an index-generating function.

Comment: There is an approach using `eval` if it **really** has to be. There are Matlab-functions returning the length or sizes of vectors or arrays. But better: Write an own implementation that does exactly what you need, it's better than using `eval` and a string (!) as index-variable.

Comment: well if you are ready to use `eval`, use it to the full extent: `idx = 'end'; eval(['vector1(' idx ')'])` will run fine and won't produce an error. I still agree with everyone else comments, this is definitely not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're trying to do two different things. In one case (defining `idx` as a scalar) you are accessing the same element in each vector. In the second case, you are asking MATLAB to potentially access a different element in each vector (unless you know for certain that each vector is the same length). You will have to treat each case differently. You could write a subfunction that does something like this

```
function element = return_element(vector, idx)
if idx <= 0
    element = vector(end);
else
    element = vector(idx);
end
end
```

You would call it like this:

```
idx = -1;
% lots of code
return_element(vector1,idx); % = vector1(end)
return_element(vector2,idx); % = vector2(end)

idx = 3;
% lots of code
return_element(vector1,idx); % = vector1(3)
return_element(vector2,idx); % = vector2(3)
```

Comment: I hoped to avoid all the if statements, and pack it in a single indexing variable in a smart way to make it more elegant. Maybe it's really not possible.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. In the first case your index is static, in the second it's dynamic. That's why I suggest packing the if statement into a sub-function, because then you only have to include it once.

Comment: Not that I recommend it, but it is possible; basically you'll have to do the MATLAB equivalent of [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) (define a classdef-class, and override `subsref` and `subsasgn` to your liking)... Otherwise you'll have to accept the existing syntax for indexing into matrices. For example, the `table` data type in recent MATLAB editions does something similar.

Comment: also you should know that `A(..,end,..)` get translated into something like `builtin('end',A,k,n)`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/object-end-indexing.html, so `end` cannot be used on its own, it needs to know the dimensions and size of the array expression in which it appears.